# Resources similar to Mosteller's 'Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability'

Tags: probability, references

Frederick Mosteller's book '[Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486653552.html)' is a collection of interesting and unusual problems. Can we collect similar resources (online or published) here? The key criteria would be that the resource is a collection of problems which are beyond standard textbook fare.

Comment: "Challenging Mathematical Problems With Elementary Solutions, Vol. 1: Combinatorial Analysis and Probability Theory" by A.M. and I.M. Yaglom.

Answer (score 1):

["Challenging Mathematical Problems With Elementary Solutions, Vol. 1: Combinatorial Analysis and Probability Theory" by A.M. and I.M. Yaglom](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0816299145)

Answer (score 1):

[Probability Through Problems by  Marek Capinski, Tomasz Jerzy Zastawniak](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/038795063X)

Answer (score 1):

Not only a problem book, but a text organized around problems, with many problems:  [Lectures on Contemporary Probability by Gregory F. Lawler,  Lester N. Coyle](https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-2/).